# How to find button created by Ajax outside Ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating table rows with delete button in it, but the problem is I am not able to find that delete button outside Ajax. So I use Ajax inside Ajax logic but I have to do it again and again. I want to use the button created by Ajax to call separate Ajax call.

My script is:

```js
 $.ajax({
      url : "{{url('addtocart')}}",
      type : "POST",
      data : {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, username:username, userType:userType,
            table_no:table_no, order_no:order_no, cname:cname,
            tname:tname, dname:dname, dish_qty:dish_qty,
            chefnote:chefnote
              },
      success : function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        $('#cartOrder').empty();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              drawRow(data[i]);
            }
        function drawRow(rowData) { 
                var row = $("<tr />")
                row.empty();
                $("#cartOrder").append(row);
                row.append($("<td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDb(this, "+rowData.dish+")'>" + rowData.dish + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td contenteditable='true' id='xyz'>" + rowData.dish_qty + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.chefnote + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>"+"<button class='btn btn-primary' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Edit"+"</button>"+" | " +"<button class='btn btn-primary' id='deletecart' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Delete"+"</button>" + "</td>"));
            }                

      //delete cart order
            $('tBody #deletecart').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $.get("{{url('deletecart')}}",{id:$(this).val()},function(data){
               // console.log(data);
                 $.ajax({
                      url : "{{url('getcart')}}",
                      type : 'GET',
                      data : {table_no:table_no},
                      success : function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#cartOrder').empty();
                          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                drawRow(data[i]);
                              }
                          function drawRow(rowData) { 
                            var row = $("<tr />")
                            row.empty();
                            $("#cartOrder").append(row);
                            row.append($("<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.dish + "</td>"));
                            row.append($("<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.dish_qty + "</td>"));
                            row.append($("<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.chefnote + "</td>"));
                            row.append($("<td>"+"<button class='btn btn-primary' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Edit"+"</button>"+" | " +"<button class='btn btn-primary' id='deletecart' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Delete"+"</button>" + "</td>"));
                          }
                      }
                });
              });
            });
          }
    });
  });
```

As you can see, first time I use Ajax to load data into table. But when I click delete, the row gets deleted from database but not from the view. So I load that table data on delete button in second Ajax. But it is not working the second time I click the delete button. It is may be because I am calling parent delete function. How can I do this?

Comment: You're still using Blade inside JS. You must understand that, at each request your whole JS will be regenerated and reloaded without caching. Your website will be significantly slower which is bad for users' expirience and for SEO.

Comment: i will be take care of it next time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with ID. You can not use same id at multiple places in same page. In your case, you need to use class instead of id.

Replace this :

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' id='deletecart' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Delete"+"</button>
```

with ?

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' class='deletecart' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Delete"+"</button>
```

As you are creating this html in loop so id is repeating. So use class and override your delete function :

```
 $('tBody .deletecart').click(function(e){
```

Comment: Actually you need to bind the delete function soon after the run time created html. otherwise it won't work

Comment: what operation you want to perform outside of ajax?? for doing so. you need to create a function outside of ajax and bind it with newly created element inside the ajax.

Comment: can u plz give any example??